# Custom iOS UINavigationBar/UITabBar and removing Tint Colors

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, customization, uitabbar, tintcolor

I am on a project where I need to create both a custom `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar`. 
My problem lies in the color of the items (the tint color!). 
I don't want any tint color for my items. I have tried to put it to clear color, but that only makes it disappear (It becomes transparent).

So, to recapitulate, I have my own images for my bar items, and they each contains their own specific colors. I have read that, in order to do what I want to do, I must subclass my `UIBar`s, but I haven't got more information than that. What should I modify in my subclass to get rid of that tint color constraint? Thank you.

EDIT : 
The tint color is not applied to the item, but to the bar (so all of the items). So my problem is that I want specific colors for my items

EDIT 2 : 
Ok I think I got it! The solution is to use `UIBarButtonItem` method : `initWithCustomView:`

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backBtn.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 26, 26);
[backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

But that only works for a `UINavigationBar` because it takes `UIBarButtonItem`. `UITabBar` on the other hand only takes `UITabBarItem` which doesn't comply with the `initWithCustomView`. So I'm still in a pickle there...

Comment: I don't understand, isn't the removal of colour the same as transparent? You could try whiteColor?

Comment: No transparent means that the tint color will be transparent, and therefore the content (lines) forming the image will become transparent. In other words, the image will become transparent (so nothing will appear even though the image will be there)

Answer (score 6):

The question was asked some time ago, but I found it in google, so someone else might also find it :)

The answer is to use this method 
`UITabBarItem(title:, image:, selectedImage:)`

With an image turning on the always original rendering mode

`image.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think I got it! The solution is to use `UIBarButtonItem` method : `initWithCustomView:`

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backBtn.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 26, 26);
[backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

But that only works for a `UINavigationBar` because it takes `UIBarButtonItem`. `UITabBar` on the other hand only takes `UITabBarItem` which doesn't comply with the `initWithCustomView`. So I'm still in a pickle there...